# Is it possible to implement a TabLayout with activities

Tags: android

I have a Tablayout kind of a bottom navigation, and I want that when the user clicks in a cardview that I have it sends him to another Tablayout but when that happens the bottom navigation does not appear anymore. That is only possible with activities right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TabLayout is just a view like any other. It can be inflated as a part of another view, or as the content view for a Fragment or an Activity. So, you're not restricted to using just an Activity with a TabLayout.

Now, if you want it so that when you click on a CardView you're taking to another screen without a TabLayout, you have a couple of options:

1. Open a new activity

Since this second Activity is going to have a different content view, it's not going to have the TabLayout from the first activity.

2. Hide the TabLayout and change the content surrounding the CardView

Since we're sticking with the first Activity, we're going to need to make all of our content changes to the views in the Activity. This means setting the visibility on the TabLayout to View.GONE and potentially lots of changes to the rest of the views depending upon what your layout contains.

I noticed that you didn't mention a ViewPager at all. Typically, this is what will be used with a TabLayout to swap between Fragments when you click on each tab. You could have all of your tabs' content in separate Fragments and then when you click on a CardView, just swap that tab's Fragment out for a different one and hide the TabLayout.

So, to answer your question, **it is easier to just open a new activity, but it is possible to not use a second activity if you want to put in the work to modify your first one in runtime.**

Comment: have you used udemy app? like when you click in a course that you are suscribed, and you can see the tabs of the videos, Q&A and ads, and it hides the bottom navigation  that's kind of what I'm looking for, how can I do it?